# How to load data dynamically upon clicking second level?

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-dropdown-tree-select

I am populating 2 level of data as shown in picture from Rest API. I have another Rest API that I need to call async to populate third level. For example, if someone clicks/expands 'Russia 1', I need to trigger HTTP Get to load childrens for 'Russia 1'.

[image]

I am trying to use loadData={this.onLoadData} but the problem is that it gets called every time, even when I am expanding 'RUSSIA' i.e. level 1. I want it to be restrictive such that it gets called only at the second level. Is there any way I can do it?

Here is the sample code https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-banzai-0zwnl

Comment: Can you post your execution code?

Comment: Added code snapshots.

Comment: Please post code for `TreeSelect`, and the code above, we also need to know where `this.state.value` is created.

Comment: Sample code added codesandbox

Comment: The problem lies with your `onChange` method. You're missing your data fetching logic for a start.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, you could put an if based on `value` and discriminate what kind of GET you want to call. Something like:

```
    onChange = (value) => {
      console.log(value);
      if (value === "2") {
         console.log("HTTP Get data Russia-1");
      } else if (value === "3") {
         console.log("HTTP Get data Russia-2");
      }
      this.setState({ value });
    };
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-euler-6rzpq?file=/index.js) your code modified.